# How to square an image and pad with transparency from the commandline (imagemagick)

Tags: imagemagick

The section entitled [Square Padding or Cropping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#square) describes a method to generate a square image--for a file whose dimensions are unknown--and pad the background with a color.

How do I perform the same operation, but create a **transparent** background.

Comment: I see you posted a comment an hour after I answered the question but you have not commented on my answer. Did it not do what you wanted?

Comment: I had just missed it.  Your solution is exactly what I was looking for (I just marked it).  Thanks!

Comment: That's good; sometimes I get confused as the order of the answers seems to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These modified methods from Anthony's examples both work for me:

```
  convert thumbnail.gif \
      \( +clone -rotate 90 +clone -mosaic +level-colors grey -transparent grey \) \
      +swap -gravity center -composite    square_padded.gif

convert thumbnail.gif  -virtual-pixel none -set option:distort:viewport \
 "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]-%[fx:max((h-w)/2,0)]-%[fx:max((w-h)/2,0)]" \
 -filter point -distort SRT 0  +repage  square_external.gif
```

Answer (score 30):

Let's make a red off-square image first, that is 300x200:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red image.png
```

[image]

Now let's put make a square image of it, but using a yellow background so you can see it:

```
convert -background yellow -gravity center image.png -resize 400x400 -extent 400x400 result.png
```

[image]

Now we can do the same thing again, but make the background transparent:

```
convert -background none -gravity center image.png -resize 400x400 -extent 400x400 result.png
```

[image]

and, just check to make sure it has worked:

```
identify result.png
result.png PNG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 418B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: This response is useful, but the question is specifically about images whose dimensions are not known beforehand.

Comment: @bmv549 Huh? The dimensions don't need to be known, I only put some in so you can see something. All you need to know is the size of the output image you want, so if you want 400x400, you put those numbers in and get 400x400 - it is not in the least bit dependent on knowing the original image size. Just do `convert -background none -gravity center image.png -resize 400x400 -extent 400x400 result.png` and it works regardless of the input size.

Comment: @bmv549 Oh, I see now - from reading the other answers. Your question just says you want a square image (which is what my answer produces) but not that the side must be the length of the longer side of the original image. I'll leave it anyway - it might help someone else.

Comment: Yes, your solution works perfect for what I would view as the more common case (i.e., where you want a particular output file size).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A pure imagemagick command would be preferable, but here's a script that uses the 'file' unix/linux command to extract the dimensions of the file which can then be used on a resize to a square of the max dimension.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'shellwords'

def dims(image_escaped)
  size_data = `file #{image_escaped}`
  size_data[/, (\d+ x \d+),/, 1].split(' x ').map(&:to_i)
end

def square(image, pad_color='transparent')
  image_esc = Shellwords.escape(image)

  maxdim = dims(image_esc).max
  geometry = "#{maxdim}x#{maxdim}"

  # could use convert if don't want to clobber the image
  system "mogrify -resize #{geometry} -background #{pad_color} -gravity center -extent #{geometry} -format png #{image_esc}"
end

ARGV.each do |image|
  square(image)
end
```

Comment: bonzo's answer is better than this, but I'm leaving this up for the record.