# ImageMagick - Squaring images of different sizes

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick

I have images of all different sizes and aspect ratios that I'm trying to convert to square with a minimum of 400x400 image size.

The first script I'm running changes any image larger than 1000x1000 down to that size, adding white background, centering, and adding 20px padding.

```
mogrify -resize '1000x1000>' -background white -gravity center -bordercolor white -border 20 -format jpg -quality 80 -path converted -strip *
```

The problem I'm having is the extent part, as I want each image to be square based on its largest dimension, which leads me to believe that it can't all be done in one line as there are some variables.

Ex:

```
355x307 --> 400x400
640x400 --> 640x640
1040x515 --> 1040x1040
494x713 --> 713x713
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: There was a similar question a couple of weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713634/how-to-square-an-image-and-pad-with-transparency-from-the-commandline-imagemagi/34992414#34992414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you just want to make a square whose sides are whatever is longest out of: `w`, `h` and `400`. If that is correct, you can do it in 2 `if` statements like this:

```
if(w>h && w>400)
   w
else if (h>400)
   h
else
   400
```

ImageMagick can tell you that in one go like this:

```
identify -format "%[fx:((w>h)&&(w>400))?w:((h>400)?h:400)]" image.jpg
```

so, if you want to get that result and make a square of that dimension, you can do:

```
dim=$(identify -format "%[fx:((w>h)&&(w>400))?w:((h>400)?h:400)]" image.jpg)
convert image.jpg -resize ${dim}x${dim) -border 20 result.jpg
```

then you would put that in a loop like this:

```
mkdir squared
for f in *.jpg; do
   dim=$(identify -format "%[fx:((w>h)&&(w>400))?w:((h>400)?h:400)]" "$f")
   convert "$f" -resize ${dim}x${dim) -border 20 squared/"$f"
done
```

Comment: Had to make a slight modification, but that seemed to do the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the expected dimensions:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read from to ; do
    x=${from%x*}
    y=${from#*x}
    if (( x > y )) ; then
        tmp=$x
        x=$y
        y=$tmp
    fi                       # We are now sure x < y
    if (( y < 400 )) ; then
        to_x=400
        to_y=400
    else
        to_x=$y
        to_y=$y
    fi
    # Verify the result is correct:
    [[ $to == $to_x'x'$to_y ]] || echo $from $to $to_x'x'$to_y
done <<EOF
355x307  400x400
640x400  640x640
1040x515 1040x1040
494x713  713x713
EOF
```

You can use `identify` to get the actual dimensions of an image.